# Numerical Methods for stochastic PDE, from rough paths to backward equations

Tags: pr.probability, na.numerical-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

this question is about some literary references regarding the state of the art in terms of numerical methods for SPDE's. In particular,

- Have the numerical implications, if any, of the results in regularity structures by Hairer been studied ? I ask this question in reference to the work done by Fritz-Victoir in the paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039607003282
- I saw a paper by Almada-Budhiraja in ejp http://ejp.ejpecp.org/article/view/2709 about backward stochastic calculus for KPZ equation in particular. Have this been further explored to apply the now vast literature of numerics in backward equations with SPDE's ?
- What is the current state of the art of the finite element methods developed with the help of stochastic chaos decompositions? see for example http://www.math.ubc.ca/~lchiaying/StochasticFEM.pdf

Thanks very much in advance!